# What if $X$ is not path connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I know that the following statement is true: $H^1(X, \mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X, x_0), \mathbb Z),$ for any path-connected pointed space $(X, x_0).$

My question is what if $X$ is not path connected, would it also still be true?

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does $H^1$ behave for a disconnected space?  $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ will only see the path component containing $x_0$ anyway.

Comment: How? Could you clarify please what you wanted to say?

Comment: it is explained precisely in the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, it could not possibly be true for a non path-connected spaces in general. Notice one object possibly depends on $x_0$ (in this case) whereas the other object is invariant; it does not depend on the basepoint. Also, consider the proof that the canonical map $\pi_1(X;x_0)\to H_1(X)$ is the Abelianisation map, for path connected $X$: to demonstrate surjectivity of this map, we most certainly need the path connectivity hypothesis. If $C$ is a path component not containing $x_0$, $1$-cycles in $C$ could not possibly lie in the image of this map, not even up to boundaries, essentially because the image of any simplex is path-connected and cannot straddle both $C$ and the component containing $x_0$.

If $X$ is any path connected space with finitely generated first cohomology and $Y$ any space with nontrivial first cohomology, then $Z:=X\sqcup Y$ will be a counterexample. If $x_0\in X,\pi_1(Z;x_0)=\pi_1(X;x_0)$ has lost all information about $Y$. Try $S^1\sqcup S^1$, for instance; $\Bbb Z^2$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

By the way, what we really care about is not that these are isomorphic in the path-connected case but that there is a nice and very explicit natural isomorphism given by associating loops with $1$-cycles.

Comment: you mean the first cohomology is invariant? Does not depend on the basepoint?

Comment: which one will give me $\mathbb Z^2$? Which theorem you used to get this? Kenneth or what?

Comment: @Brain Nowhere in the definition of (co)homology are basepoints referred to. This is arguably one reason why (co)homology is nice since it is somehow only about the space itself and not about specific points. The **Künneth** formula is not needed to get $\Bbb Z^2$, only the straightforward fact that $H^\ast(\bigsqcup_i X_i)\cong\prod_i H^\ast(X_i)$

Comment: So what path connectedness exactly do? Why we need the disjoint union in our example? Is the intersection between $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be zero?

Comment: @Brain In the disjoint union  space the subspaces $X,Y$ are disjoint. This can confuse people but they are even disjoint in the case of $X\sqcup X$; you just make a ‘copy’ of $X$ which is set theoretically distinct from the other copy. We try not to worry too much about specific set theoretic implementations as they obstruct the ideas

Comment: You should know that if there is a path $x_0\to x_1$ we get an induced isomorphism on $\pi_1$, so in the path connected case the base point somehow isn’t that important. But isn’t necessarily the case in a disconnected setting; in $S^1\sqcup\Bbb R$, the $\pi_1$ is either trivial or nontrivial depending on your basepoint